# WPF How to inherit style with color animation to change the color

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to create a common `Button` style with redefined template and animations for transition between mouse in, out, up, down and disabled and enabled states. That's not a problem, but I want to make another button style, which is basically the same except for the background color.

I have colors defined for the *Normal*, *Hover* and *Disabled* states in style resources as well as Storyboards:

```
<Style.Resources>
    <Color x:Key="DisabledBackground">#4c4c4c</Color>
    <Color x:Key="NormalBackground">#538ce1</Color>
    <Color x:Key="HoverBackground">#6ea8ff</Color>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation">
        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                        To="{StaticResource HoverBackground}"
                        Duration="0:0:0.3" />

        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Underlay"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         To="0.7"
                         Duration="0:0:0.3" />
    </Storyboard>

    <!-- and few others... -->
</Style>
```

Then I have customized template and finally the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MouseOverAnimation}"/>
    </Trigger.EnterActions>

    <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MouseOutAnimation}"/>
    </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>

<!-- and few others... -->
```

Now what I want is to create new style and just change the color of `DisabledBackground` and `NormalBackground` like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Start"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBackground">#4c4c4c</Color>
        <Color x:Key="NormalBackground">#960a0a</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HoverBackground">#de1111</Color>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

And let the control template untouched. You have probably noticed that I used `DynamicResource` in my common button style to refer storyboards in style resources which ends with exception because storyboards can't have binding or dynamic resources. This is my last "solution" which does not work but I couldn't came up with anything else.

I do not want to copy and paste my whole button style just to change *two* colors. How can I modify my style, to be able to "dynamically" change the colors used in storyboard animations or at least inherit the style and set the colors there?

### Complete XAML

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

    <Style.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="DisabledBackground">#4c4c4c</Color>
        <Color x:Key="NormalBackground">#538ce1</Color>
        <Color x:Key="HoverBackground">#6ea8ff</Color>

        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource HoverBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Underlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.7" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation" FillBehavior="Stop">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource NormalBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Underlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.2" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseDownAnimation">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverlayGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.45" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MouseUpAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" FillBehavior="Stop">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverlayGradient" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.5" Duration="0:0:0.1" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="DisabledAnimation">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource DisabledBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlayFillBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource DisabledBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Key="EnabledAnimation">
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource NormalBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="UnderlayFillBrush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="{StaticResource NormalBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
        </Storyboard>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                <Grid>

                    <!-- Button underlay glow

                    -->
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Underlay" Opacity="0.2">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="UnderlayFillBrush" Color="{DynamicResource NormalBackground}"/>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>

                        <Rectangle.Effect>
                            <BlurEffect Radius="35" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                        </Rectangle.Effect>
                    </Rectangle>

                    <!-- Button base border with rounded corners

                    Contains base background
                    -->
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.8"/>
                        </Border.BorderBrush>

                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="BackgroundBrush" Color="{DynamicResource NormalBackground}"/>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <!-- Button Overlay

                        Adds the background overlay gradient -->
                        <Border CornerRadius="2">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush x:Name="OverlayGradient" Opacity="0.5" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.02" Color="White"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.02" Color="Transparent"/>
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.85" Color="#000000" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>


                            <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#b4b4b4" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                </Border.BorderBrush>

                                <!-- Inner text -->
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                           Foreground="White"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
                                           RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">
                                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="6" Color="Black" RenderingBias="Quality"/>
                                    </TextBlock.Effect>
                                </TextBlock>

                            </Border>

                        </Border>

                    </Border>

                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource DisabledAnimation}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource EnabledAnimation}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MouseOverAnimation}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MouseOutAnimation}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MouseDownAnimation}"/>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>

                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource MouseUpAnimation}"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>


        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx):

> You can't use dynamic resource references or data binding expressions
>   to set Storyboard or animation property values. That's because
>   everything inside a Style must be thread-safe, and the timing system
>   must Freeze Storyboard objects to make them thread-safe. A Storyboard
>   cannot be frozen if it or its child timelines contain dynamic resource
>   references or data binding expressions. For more information about
>   freezing and other [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx) features, see the [Freezable Objects
>   Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx).

You can certainly use a super hacks, etc., but in your case, in my opinion, it's easier to use a different style or colors in resources. It will not be so difficult.

For more information see:

[MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx)

[Similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/9336022f-badb-4b40-a86c-a50ab1a64ba5/)

Comment: Yes, I have found this quote and I though that inheriting style and changing only part of the parent style including animations must be pretty common operation. Apparently I was wrong but thank you for your answer.

Comment: Those MSDN links are dead. :(

Answer (score 0):

Although its been years since this question was asked and answered I have some useful information for others to keep in mind so you don't make the same mistake I did years ago when trying to solve this problem.

**TLDR**
Be very cautious about using **ComponentResourceKey** as a way to use make your dynamic resource static so that you can use it with freezables.  It will compile, it may even run but you got lucky and it probably shouldn't even be allowed in the first place as it could save people from walking off a cliff.  See code example at the bottom, don't do that with **freezables**.

**Full Details**
Like others, I wanted to keep my resources as flexible as possible.  I was aware that we cannot use Dynamic Resources for animations but came across a 'clever' way around this with code similar to the following example.  The key here (no pun intended) was to use the **ComponentResourceKey**.  After I used this approach a year or so ago I was nearly break dancing on the floor when it worked with the animations.  At first glance you might be thinking, *"Well of course this worked, you used a static resource per your code example"*. However, once you become aware that the **ComponentResourceKey** is a markup extension that provides 'super powers' that let you refer to a resource that may not even exist in the current assembly **and** you don't have to include that assembly as a reference, it becomes easier to understand that this effectively translates to a pseudo dynamic resource.

In the case of a freezable, I believe this was working for me at the time because I accidentally created an initialization ordering that made this appear to work.  That is the value was defined before it was first consumed.  Then over this weekend (and now years later) I started to dump all of my bin/obj and ext files into a common location where they could easily be clobbered by my build system so I would feel confident I had a clean build.  Suddenly, I began hitting fatal xaml exceptions indicating that the ComponentResourceKey's I used in some locations were not defined.  I then directly included the assemblies right where they were used rather than in the main exe.  I knew this went against what I was trying to avoid (coupling) but it was after midnight and I wanted it to compile before I retired, but it still crashed with the same XAML exceptions.

After I overcame the

> well it worked for over a year, it must be something I changed
>   recently

feeling that we all have, it became clear as day that what I was doing shouldn't have even be used in the first place.  I think **the "good programmer" in us always wants to be as flexible and decoupled as possible, even if that means coming up with some really creative techniques** that satisfy our need to solve the problem in our faces that day.

> In addition to truly clobbering the binaries between builds, I also
>   turned about 128 libraries into Nuget packages and I think this
>   somehow affected the initialization ordering of when the key's value
>   was set vs. when it was used.  It all seemed like voodoo after midnight.

I still think that using the **ComponentResourceKey** markup extension can be a great way of decoupling xaml library inter-dependencies, you just cannot use them safely with freezables such as those in storyboard animations.  Back when I first applied this technique, I didn't try to dynamically change the value during runtime as for me this was merely a stretch goal and I knew that someday I would look back and be glad I took the time to make it that flexible. (Now I wish I had that time back!)

Example of using a **ComponentResourceKey**
Don't do this with **freezables**

```
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:.1">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:SettingKeys}, ResourceId=DefaultButtonClickBackgroundBrush}}" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

BTW, here is an example of defining the key in case you want to apply this technique to anything other than freezables.  Note that the local:SettingKeys is just an empty C Sharp class, google the technique to fully understand.

`<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type local:SettingKeys},ResourceId=DefaultButtonClickBackgroundBrush}" Color="#FE8D00" />`

If this saves someone else one headache, I will be happy.  Like the accepted answer's author stated, you can use creative hacks but you should avoid them or walk off a cliff like me.